# An IIS web site uses the "default document" list from another web site

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-6, configuration, default-document

We have an IIS 6 on Windows 2008. We have multiple web sites on this server.

Two of those sites have the same physical path.
- One should have the Default.aspx page as default document ;
- The other one should have index_syfab.asp as default document, which simply does a redirection on Default.aspx?lid=4.

The problem is, if I add index_syfab.asp as default document in the second web site, it also adds it to the first. If I delete it from the first, it also deletes it from the second. How can I stop it from doing that ?

We don't have an URL rewriting module installed, so for now it's out of the question.

We use the exact same technique, with the exact same configuration, but on another server, with windows 2003 and IIS 5. And it works perfectly.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, though you have IIS 6 installed on Windows Server 2008, your Web Sites are configured on IIS 7.

Since both the Web Sites are pointed to the same physical location e.g. C:\inetpub\wwwroot the `<defaultDocument>` configuration is happening in the same web.config file which is located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

It was possible to have different defaultDocument configured in IIS 6, because the configuration was stored in Metabase.xml file.

Comment: Well, you're right. I guess I'm stuck with URL Rewriting. Thanks :(

Comment: Another question though : what's that about IIS6 and 7 ?